# Is there any error metric like accuracy (the percentage) for regression model assessment?

Tags: regression, error, accuracy

Is there any error metric like accuracy (the percentage or the misclassification rate) for regression model assessment? since the percentage shows more directly how the model performance is. Particularly, when it's not necessary to compare with others models.

Comment: A relevant thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/414349/is-my-model-any-good-based-on-the-diagnostic-metric-r2-auc-accuracy-e

Answer (score 1):

The Mean Square Error, Mean Absolute Percentage Error, Coefficient of Determination (R^2 or Adjusted R^2) are three metrics that come to mind immediately.